# Interaction between Crypt::RSA (Perl) and java.security.Signature (Java)

Tags: java, rsa, signature, verification

I'd like to sign a file by using a RSA keypair. For this purpose I have this Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Crypt::RSA;

my $data = ... # File contents

my $rsa = new Crypt::RSA; 
my $key = new Crypt::RSA::Key::Private(Filename => "stackoverflow.priv", Password => "*****");
my $signature = $rsa->sign(Message => $data, Key => $key, Armour => 0);

# Write signature to file
```

On the client side, I'd like to use the following Java function to verify the file:

```
private static final String PUBLICKEY_MOD = "190343051422614110006523776876348493...";
private static String PUBLICKEY_EXP = "65537";

public boolean check() {
     byte[] data = ... // Data
     byte[] dataSignature = ... // Signature (as calculated in the Perl script)

     Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");

     signature.initVerify(getPublicKey());
     signature.update(data);
     return signature.verify(dataSignature);
}

private PublicKey getPublicKey() {
    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(PUBLICKEY_MOD), new BigInteger(PUBLICKEY_EXP));
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return factory.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

However, `check()` always reports false. These things I already checked:

- `data` and `dataSignature` are correctly read
- `PUBLICKEY_MOD` and `PUBLICKEY_EXP` are correct
- `getPublicKey()` returns a PublicKey which has the correct attributes
- the private key and the public key are part of the same pair

Does anyone know how to verify the file correctly? Is `signature` correctly instanced?

Comment: Thank you very much! I fixed these two issues and it works perfectly. If you'd like to add your points as an answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: Could you indicate what you did to get SHA-256 to work for PERL, there is [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142381/is-there-a-perl-implementation-of-sha256withrsa)...

Comment: What did you do? I am stuck in same position. Tried to make both the change but didnt work. In SCALA it looks like `var signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA" )` and in PERL `$publickey->verify_message($signature, $datatosign, 'SHA256', 'v1.5')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first clue that something might be wrong is that you never tell Perl what hash function to use, but you tell Java to use SHA256. You have a lot of work to do on the Perl side. Also, the default padding scheme for Crypt::RSA seems to be PSS, whereas for Java it is PKCSv1.5