# Is there a perl implementation of SHA256withRSA

Tags: perl, cryptography, pkcs#1

I need to be able to craft JSON Web Token signatures (which only accepts ['RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function'](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#computingsignature) signatures), but the obvious CPAN contender for this task ([Crypt::RSA](http://search.cpan.org/~vipul/Crypt-RSA/lib/Crypt/RSA.pm)) will only generate signatures using [MD2, MD5 or SHA1](http://search.cpan.org/~vipul/Crypt-RSA/lib/Crypt/RSA/SS/PKCS1v15.pm#new%28%29).

Is there another library somewhere that will do what I want? If necessary I should be able to do a bit of hacking to get there, but that wouldn't be too pretty.

Comment: [`Digest::SHA`?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Digest::SHA)

Comment: @mob but how to configure Crypt::RSA with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find a module that did what I wanted: [Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA/)

```
my $rsa = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($key);
$rsa->use_sha256_hash;
my $signature = $rsa->sign($message);
```

So much easier than extending Crypt::RSA, but it was oddly kind of difficult to find.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you had to modify the 'Crypt::RSA::SS::PKCS1v15.pm' to add the SHA256 supporting. It is not so difficult, you can try this patched version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -sw
##
## Crypt::RSA::SS:PKCS1v15
##
## Copyright (c) 2001, Vipul Ved Prakash.  All rights reserved.
## This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
## it under the same terms as Perl itself.
##
## $Id: PKCS1v15.pm,v 1.6 2001/06/22 23:27:38 vipul Exp $

package Crypt::RSA::SS::PKCS1v15;
use strict;
use base 'Crypt::RSA::Errorhandler';
use Crypt::RSA::DataFormat qw(octet_len os2ip i2osp h2osp);
use Crypt::RSA::Primitives;
use Crypt::RSA::Debug qw(debug);
use Digest::SHA qw(sha1 sha256);
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5);
use Digest::MD2 qw(md2);
use Math::Pari qw(floor);

$Crypt::RSA::SS::PKCS1v15::VERSION = '1.99.1';

sub new { 

    my ($class, %params) = @_;
    my $self = bless { 
                       primitives => new Crypt::RSA::Primitives, 
                       digest     => $params{Digest} || 'SHA1',
                       encoding   => { 
                                        MD2 => "0x 30 20 30 0C 06 08 2A 86 48
                                                   86 F7 0D 02 02 05 00 04 10",
                                        MD5 => "0x 30 20 30 0C 06 08 2A 86 48
                                                   86 F7 0D 02 05 05 00 04 10",
                                       SHA1 => "0x 30 21 30 09 06 05 2B 0E 03
                                                   02 1A 05 00 04 14",
                                       SHA256 => "0x 30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 
                                                     48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 
                                                     00 04 20",
                                     },
                       VERSION    => $Crypt::RSA::SS::PKCS1v15::VERSION,
                     }, $class;           
    if ($params{Version}) { 
        # do versioning here
    }
    return $self;

}


sub sign { 

    my ($self, %params) = @_; 
    my $key = $params{Key}; my $M = $params{Message} || $params{Plaintext};
    return $self->error ("No Message or Plaintext parameter", \$key, \%params) unless $M;
    return $self->error ("No Key parameter", \$M, \%params) unless $key;
    my $k = octet_len ($key->n);

    my $em; 
    unless ($em = $self->encode ($M, $k-1)) { 
        return $self->error ($self->errstr, \$key, \%params, \$M) 
            if $self->errstr eq "Message too long.";
        return $self->error ("Modulus too short.", \$key, \%params, \$M)
            if $self->errstr eq "Intended encoded message length too short";
    }

    my $m = os2ip ($em);
    my $sig = $self->{primitives}->core_sign (Key => $key, Message => $m);
    return i2osp ($sig, $k);

}    


sub verify { 

    my ($self, %params) = @_;
    my $key = $params{Key}; my $M = $params{Message} || $params{Plaintext};
    my $S = $params{Signature}; 
    return $self->error ("No Message or Plaintext parameter", \$key, \%params) unless $M;
    return $self->error ("No Key parameter", \$M, \$S, \%params) unless $key;
    return $self->error ("No Signature parameter", \$key, \$M, \%params) unless $S;
    my $k = octet_len ($key->n);
    return $self->error ("Invalid signature.", \$key, \$M, \%params) if length($S) != $k;
    my $s = os2ip ($S);
    my $m = $self->{primitives}->core_verify (Key => $key, Signature => $s) || 
        $self->error ("Invalid signature.", \$M, $key, \%params);
    my $em = i2osp ($m, $k-1) || 
        return $self->error ("Invalid signature.", \$M, \$S, $key, \%params);
    my $em1; 
    unless ($em1 = $self->encode ($M, $k-1)) { 
        return $self->error ($self->errstr, \$key, \%params, \$M) 
            if $self->errstr eq "Message too long.";
        return $self->error ("Modulus too short.", \$key, \%params, \$M)
            if $self->errstr eq "Intended encoded message length too short.";
    }

    debug ("em: $em"); debug ("em1: $em1");

    return 1 if $em eq $em1;
    return $self->error ("Invalid signature.", \$M, \$key, \%params);

}


sub encode { 

    my ($self, $M, $emlen) = @_;

    my $H;
    if    ($self->{digest} eq "SHA1") { $H = sha1 ($M) }
    elsif ($self->{digest} eq "SHA256" ) { $H = sha256 ($M) }
    elsif ($self->{digest} eq "MD5" ) { $H =  md5 ($M) }
    elsif ($self->{digest} eq "MD2" ) { $H =  md2 ($M) }

    my $alg = h2osp($self->{encoding}->{$self->{digest}});
    my $T = $alg . $H;
    $self->error ("Intended encoded message length too short.", \$M) if $emlen < length($T) + 10;
    my $pslen = $emlen - length($T) - 2;
    my $PS = chr(0xff) x $pslen;
    my $em = chr(1) . $PS . chr(0) . $T; 
    return $em;

}


sub version { 
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{VERSION};
}


sub signblock { 
    return -1;
}


sub verifyblock { 
    my ($self, %params) = @_;
    return octet_len($params{Key}->n);
}


1;
```

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like that's pretty much the way I'll have to go. I'll do it as a new module (something like Crypt::RSA::SS::PKCS1v15::SHA256) rather than just patching it locally though. Cheers.

Comment: @Cebjyre I agree with you. Have a new module looks more reasonable for this. ;)

Comment: I got stuck into making the new module, then I realised that `Crypt::RSA` uses its own wacky key file format, so I went for another hunt and found `Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA`. There's a decent chance I'll still do a module to handle the entire JWT process, but fortunately I don't have to worry about this particular component anymore.